# JQuery todo list not running

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a todo list where you type a task in a box and click the add button to enter the item into the list. However, nothing is getting added to my list, and I can't figure out what is wrong with my code.

```js
  $(document).ready( function() {   
  
    $('#add_todo').click( function() {
      var todoDescription = $('#todo_description').val();
      
      $('.todo_list').prepend('<div class="todo">'
         '<div>'
           '<input type="checkbox" class="check_todo" name="check_todo"/>'
         '</div>'
         '<div class="todo_description">'
           todoDescription
         '</div>'
       '</div>');
      
      $('#todo_form')[0].reset();
      
      $('.check_todo').unbind('click');
      $('.check_todo').click( function() {
        var todo = $(this).parent().parent();
        todo.toggleClass('checked');
      });
      return false;
            
    });  
    
    
  });
```

```css
body {
 font-family: kristen itc;
 background-image="css/fzm-notebook.texture-25.jpg";
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
}

.title {
 text-align: center;
 margin-top:  80px;
 font-size: 40px;

}

.item {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    }

  .dashed{
   font-size: 25px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"> 
 </head>

    
   <body background="css/fzm-notebook.texture-25.jpg" no-repeat;>
    <div class="title">
        <h1>Shopping List</h1>
   <div class="enter_todo">
        <form id="todo_form" action="index.html" method="POST">
            <input type="text" size="55" id="todo_description" name="todo_description"/>
            <input type="submit" id="add_todo" value="Add"/>
        </form>
   </div>
</div>

   <div class="todo_list">
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have multiline strings in JS. You seem to know that, but you forgot to concatenate them with the plus sign. This is the problematic part:

```
$('.todo_list').prepend('<div class="todo">'
     '<div>'
       '<input type="checkbox" class="check_todo" name="check_todo"/>'
     '</div>'
     '<div class="todo_description">'
       todoDescription
     '</div>'
   '</div>');
```

Just add a `+` to the end of each line except the last one.

Other than that, your code looks fine, let's try it:

```js
$(document).ready( function() {   
  
    $('#add_todo').click( function() {
      var todoDescription = $('#todo_description').val();
      
      $('.todo_list').prepend('<div class="todo">' +
         '<div>' +
           '<input type="checkbox" class="check_todo" name="check_todo"/>' +
         '</div>' +
         '<div class="todo_description">' +
           todoDescription +
         '</div>' +
       '</div>');
      
      $('#todo_form')[0].reset();
      
      $('.check_todo').unbind('click');
      $('.check_todo').click( function() {
        var todo = $(this).parent().parent();
        todo.toggleClass('checked');
      });
      return false;
            
    });  
    
    
  });
```

```css
body {
 font-family: kristen itc;
 background-image="css/fzm-notebook.texture-25.jpg";
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
}

.title {
 text-align: center;
 margin-top:  80px;
 font-size: 40px;

}

.item {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    }

  .dashed{
   font-size: 25px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div class="title">
        <h1>Shopping List</h1>
   <div class="enter_todo">
        <form id="todo_form" action="index.html" method="POST">
            <input type="text" size="55" id="todo_description" name="todo_description"/>
            <input type="submit" id="add_todo" value="Add"/>
        </form>
   </div>
</div>

   <div class="todo_list">
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work...

Here is your code modified :

```
<script>
$(document).ready( function() {

    $('#add_todo').click( function() {
        var todoDescription = $('#todo_description').val();
        $('.todo_list').prepend('<div class="todo"><div><input type="checkbox" class="check_todo" name="check_todo"/></div><div class="todo_description">'+todoDescription+'</div></div>');
        $('#todo_form')[0].reset();
        $('.check_todo').unbind('click');
        $('.check_todo').click( function() {
            var todo = $(this).parent().parent();
            todo.toggleClass('checked');
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

I just deleted all quote on your html inside `$('.todo_list').prepend('<div class="todo"><div><input type="checkbox" class="check_todo" name="check_todo"/></div><div class="todo_description">'+todoDescription+'</div></div>');`

And add "+" around "todoDescription"

Hope this will help :)

### EDIT

Forget to mention that i've deleted your action in your form...

```
<form id="todo_form" method="POST">
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your console, you have forgotten all of the `+` needed to concactenate your html string:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('#add_todo').click(function() {
  var todoDescription = $('#todo_description').val();

  $('.todo_list').prepend('<div class="todo">'+
  '<div>'+
  '<input type="checkbox" class="check_todo" name="check_todo"/>'+
  '</div>'+
  '<div class="todo_description">'+
  todoDescription +'</div>'+
  '</div>');

  $('#todo_form')[0].reset();

  $('.check_todo').unbind('click');
  $('.check_todo').click(function() {
   var todo = $(this).parent().parent();
   todo.toggleClass('checked');
  });
  return false;

 });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="title">
  <h1>Shopping List</h1>
  <div class="enter_todo">
    <form id="todo_form" action="index.html" method="POST">
      <input type="text" size="55" id="todo_description" name="todo_description" />
    </form>
    <input type="button" id="add_todo" value="Add" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="todo_list">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

As others have mentioned, you didn't concatenate the strings correctly.

Multiline strings and string interpolation can be used with template strings, introduced in ES6.

You could format the string in the following way using a template string :

```
`<div class="todo">
     <div>
     <input type="checkbox" class="check_todo" name="check_todo"/>
     </div>
     <div class="todo_description">
      ${todoDescription}
     </div>
   </div>`
```

Comment: what about browsers that don't support backticks for strings?